# C++ any way place class definition after main() function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm writing a small C++ program and need to keep all the code in a single file.  In it, I have a class definition. I would like to put the class definition AFTER the main() function. When attempting to do this, the compiler in visual studio complains as it seems class definitions must come before the main() function.

This there a way that I can place the class definition AFTER the main() function? Perhaps with some sort of macro or precompiler trick? It's fine if the code gets compiled with the class def before main, but in the raw source, I need the class def after main.

```
int main(){

    someClass object;
    //remainder of code

}


class someClass{

    //class code
}
```

Comment: No. just put it before `main`.

Comment: You have to put it before or else the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about when it sees `someClass`.

Comment: You *might*, just *might* be able to do this by `#include`ing itself and using include guards. But, why? Is this a quiz?

Comment: Reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: There is no requirement that class definitions must follow the `main` function. The requirement is that you can't refer to a class before it's declared, or to a class's members before it's been defined. It would be helpful if you'd update your question to show the actual error message you got.

Comment: Definitely not a quiz question. It's a project that I'm working on where for other complex reasons I need to have my main function at the top of this file.

Comment: Is there any kind of precompiler trick to solve this? Like some way to #define a whole block of code to the top which was physically defined down below?

Comment: @Michael _'I need to have my main function at the top of this file'_ without being able to put any include statements before??? Weird!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work but it is truly horrible. If I could downvote my own answer, I would. Please don't do this in production.

Assume the file is `test.cc`

```
#if defined(guard)
int main(){
    someClass object;
}
#endif

#if !defined(guard)
class someClass
{

};
#define guard
#include "test.cc"
#endif
```

Comment: +1 for evil genius. Also +infinity to **please don't do this** :)

Comment: You can write `#include __FILE__` to bypass the filename requirement

Comment: haha thanks for the response. I wish I could say why I need things done this way but I can't. And I fully understand why you wouldn't normally want to do things this way.. but for this project's case, I have to. :)

Comment: @Michael: Yes I think the only way is to rely on the preprocessor to produce valid C++. That's why I went down this route.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first provide full declaration before you can use your class.

You could forward declare the class, but until you provide full declaration, you can only use name of class as pointer (can't allocated objects on stack) and can't call methods.

```
class someClass;

int main() {
    someClass* sc;
    // can't allocated sc on heap (new someClass) or call any mehtods (sc->someMethod())
}

class someClass {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class definition. I would like to put the class definition
> AFTER the main() function.

## Don`t try to do it.

Generally any sane compiler would not allow it, but even if it allows though some insane non standard compiler option, or weird hacks, it would be a horrible code that will stink though out its life time.
C++ is flexible enough but you need to understand and honor its grammar. You cannot instantiate an incomplete or absent class/structure, because the compiler needs to know the size of the object its instantiating and without a Class Declaration it would not be possible,

Comment: I'm not writing a normal program here. I fully understand why normally we would not want to do this. Wish I could share more about the reasoning but I can't. So just looking for a way...

Answer (score 0):

Put your `someClass` declaration in a header file, and then `#include` that header file at the top of your program.

Comment: @juanchopanza That seems like an unnecessary requirement to me. There is no solution given that constraint.

Comment: +1. Yes this does not satisfy the OP requirements but, realistically, it is the best approach.

Comment: I'm not writing a normal program here. I fully understand why normally we would want to do this. Wish I could share more about the reasoning but I can't. So just looking for a way...

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do this.**

Further, to arrive at this constraint, something has gone wrong in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to guess the reason: it's an autogenerated text and its parts are generated by different mechanisms, which call sequence can't be reordered. If so, I could suggest to use a base class, which definition could be placed before main and derive your someClass from that baseClass. This way you can call any required method from baseClass.